# Как заблокировать RadioButton после выбора?

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть несколько `RadioButton` и при выборе одного из них нужно блокировать другие. Как можно  это реализовать?

Comment: Покажите, что уже сделали и где по вашему не получается.

Comment: Если при выборе одного из них вы заблокируете остальные, то как вы потом выберете другое значение?

Comment: https://github.com/Drein211/test-for-the-personnel-department-prefecture-SZAO вот что есть сейчас

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Следует написать универсальный метод, который при выборе `radioButton` будет вызываться у каждого `radioButton`, а внутри метода будем менять их состояния:

```
void radioButtons_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton currentRadioButton = sender as RadioButton; // на кого кликнули
    if (radioButton != null)
    {
        // пройдем по всем RadioButton нашей формы и поменяем состояние
        foreach(var radioButton in this.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>()) 
        {
            radioButton.Enabled = false; // заблокируем каждый
        }
        currentRadioButton.Enabled = true; // разблокируем выбранный
    }
}
```

Таким образом после выбора одного `radioButton` остальные будут заблокированы. Для того, чтобы данный метод вызывался у всех `radioButton`, размещенных на форме, необходимо в свойствах этих компонент, у каждого, задать метод, который будет вызываться для события `CheckedChanged` - вызвать метод `radioButtons_CheckedChanged`.

Answer (score -1):

[image: До деактивации][image: после деактивации]

Доброго времени суток. Для деактивации (блокировки) radio button, после выбора необходимо написать след. код:
функция создается автоматически, после нажатия несколько раз мышкой по radio button

```
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

Enabled = false; //деактивируем radio button

}
```

Для деактивации других radio button необходимо деактивировать их след. образом:

```
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Enabled = false;
   radioButton2.Enabled = false; // название radio button . деактивация = деактивировать
   radioButton3.Enabled = false;
}
```

для того, чтобы вырубить всю форму, нужно просто написать в функцию след. строчку:

Form1.ActiveForm.Dispose();

Comment: нет: //деактивируем всю форму

Comment: остановитесь, при чем здесь `Dispose`?